# What is the tonalilty/mode of Sitting on the dock of the bay -Ottis Redding?

Tags: chords, harmony, chord-progressions, key

I was wondering what is the tonality of Sitting on the dock of the bay (

) since no diatonic scales fit the chord progression.

Here is the chord progression :
G | B7 | C | A7 .

On the chord sheet I have it is wrote that the key is G but the chords B7 and G7 aren't in key. Thus my question is what is happening here ?

Comment: Until that A7, I was reminded of the chord progression of Radiohead's "Creep", which is G | B | C | Cm.

Comment: Not just something its about the half of the chords

Comment: It is in G. Being "in G" does not mean that there can only be G major diatonic notes. The home note is G and the home chord is G major. Home is where the song could end. If there's a non-diatonic note or chord, it just means that at least during that chord, the perceived current scale is changed, there's a chromatic alteration. During the B7 chord, D is raised to D#. During A7, C is raised to C#. The B7 chord makes you feel like, Em would be a suitable easy-choice next chord. But it slips to C instead. A7 makes you feel a D chord would fit next, but it goes straight back home to G instead.

Comment: @Richard It's a basic analysis question but I'm quite sure that closing the question will not make the OP any more capable of performing that basic analysis. There are beginners who cannot do even the simplest and most trivial things. I wonder what would be the correct way to ask about how to do that.

Comment: The real question that the OP should ask is, what happens if there is a non-diatonic note in a chord. And the answer is: then that scale degree is chromatically altered at least for the duration of that chord. This should be basic Music 101 stuff.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica I guess the issue is how we define "basic" in "basic analysis questions." I agree that your re-framing of the question is more suitable, but I also wonder if we already have too many of those questions as it is. Please feel free to vote to re-open if you feel strongly enough!